# I have having a rendering and timing issue with components that are rendering in my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react project. The react project is calling the yelp api and rendering businesses from the yelp api. In this component, there is a `useEffect` that is being called right when the screen loads to grab the coffee shops details. When the state for `shopDetails` is updated, there is another `useEffect` that is making another request to grab the business reviews and update the state `shopReviews`. Everything is rendering correctly.

I am running into an issue because I want to load the business hours that is located in the `shopDetails.hours`. The issue is that it is trying to `map` through the hours before the hours has mounted and the state was updated. It then immediatly throws an error says that it can't iterate through `undefined`.

In the jsx, I have a if statement that checks to see if the hours mounted and if it is mounted, then just map through the hours and display them. If not, just render loading. What it is doing is just checking one time when it first renders and then is not updating and rechecking when the hours are set in state.

I have no idea how to get the if statment in the jsx to update when the state is updated... can anyone please help...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import caffinderLogo from "../assets/caffinder-logo.png";
import Button from "./Button";
import "../components/CoffeeShop.css";
import { useParams, useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export default function CoffeeShop() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id, name } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const all_data = location.state?.all_data;

  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  const [shopDetails, setShopDetails] = useState({});
  const [hours, setHours] = useState([]);

  const DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];

  const MONTHS = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  let url_link_details = "http://localhost:1111/api/yelp/details";
  let url_link_reviews = "http://localhost:1111/api/yelp/reviews";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(url_link_details, {
        all_data,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        let updatedHours = response.data.hours[0];
        response.data.hours = updatedHours;
        console.log(response.data);
        setShopDetails(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(url_link_reviews, {
        all_data,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setReviews(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    // setHours(shopDetails.hours);
  }, [shopDetails]);

  const formatHours = (hour) => {
    let timing = hour.split("");
    if (timing[0] == 0) {
      timing.shift();
      timing.splice(1, 0, ":");
      timing.join("");
      return timing;
    } else {
      let time = timing[0] + timing[1];
      let newTime = parseInt(time);
      if (newTime > 12) {
        let timeOverTime = newTime - 12;
        let currentTiming = timeOverTime.toString() + ":00";
        return currentTiming;
      } else {
        timing.splice(2, 0, ":");
        timing.join("");
        return timing;
      }
    }
  };

  const formatTimeCreated = (time) => {
    let dayTime = "";
    let splitCreated = time.split(" ");
    let postDate = splitCreated[0];
    let splitDate = postDate.split("-");
    let year = splitDate[0];
    let monthInt = parseInt(splitDate[1]);
    let month = MONTHS[monthInt];
    let day = splitDate[2];
    return `${month} ${day}, ${year}`;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="shop-container">
        <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go Back</button>
        <a href={all_data.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <img src={all_data.image_url} className="c-s-image" alt="logo" />
        </a>
        <h1 className="shop-name">{all_data.name}</h1>
        <div className="shop-rating">
          <p>Rating: {all_data.rating} / 5</p>
          <p>Price: {all_data.price}</p>
        </div>
        <a
          href={`http://maps.google.com/?q=${all_data.location.address1} ${all_data.location.city}, ${all_data.location.state} ${all_data.location.zip_code}`}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer noopener"
        >
          <p>{all_data.location.address1}</p>
          <p>
            {all_data.location.city}, {all_data.location.state}{" "}
            {all_data.location.zip_code}
          </p>
        </a>
        <div>
          <p>Current Hours: {hours.is_open_now ? "Open" : "Closed"}</p>
----------------------------------- issue --------------------------------
          {shopDetails ? (
            shopDetails.hours.open.map((hour) => {
              return (
                <div className="shop-hours">
                  <p>{DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK[hour.day]}</p>
                  <p>
                    Opens: {formatHours(hour.start)} a.m. - Closes:{" "}
                    {formatHours(hour.end)} p.m.
                  </p>
                </div>
              );
            })
            // <p>Hello</p>
          ) : (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className="review-header">Reviews: </p>
          {reviews.map((review) => {
            return (
              <div className="review" key={review.id}>
                <div></div>
                <p>{review.user.name}</p>
                <div className="rating-created">
                  <p>Overall Rating: {review.rating} / 5</p>
                  <p>{formatTimeCreated(review.time_created)}</p>
                </div>
                <p>{review.text}</p>
                <div></div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Add A Review</legend>
            <label for="stacked-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="stacked-name" placeholder="Name" />
            <br></br>
            <label for="stacked-email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="stacked-email" placeholder="Email" />
            <br></br>
            <label for="stacked-rating">Rating</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="stacked-rating"
              min="0"
              max="5"
              step=".5"
            />
            <br></br>
            <label for="stacked-review">Review</label>
            <input type="blurb" id="stacked-review" placeholder="Review" />
            <br></br>
            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
              Add Reivew
            </button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = {
  businessInfoBox: {
    border: "solid orange 1px",
    width: "70vw",
    padding: "0 20px",
    borderRadius: 20,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "start",
  },
};
```

Here is the error that I am getting when it wants to render before the hours is mounted

[image]

--------------------------- UPDATE ----------------------

So when I set the hours state right after the data is retrieved from the api, everything loads with no issue for immediate rendering.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(url_link_details, {
        all_data,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        let updatedHours = response.data.hours[0];
        response.data.hours = updatedHours;
        console.log(response.data);
        setShopDetails(response.data);
        setHours(response.data.hours[0].open);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

this works correctly. The issue is that when it comes to the jsx, it shows loading on the screen and does not update when the content is updated in the state. here is the jsx

```
          {hours.length > 0 ? (
            hours.map((hour) => {
              return (
                <div className="shop-hours">
                  <p>{DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK[hour.day]}</p>
                  <p>
                    Opens: {formatHours(hour.start)} a.m. - Closes:{" "}
                    {formatHours(hour.end)} p.m.
                  </p>
                </div>
              );
            })
          ) : (
            // <p>Hello</p>
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )}
```

how can I force react to recheck of the `hours.length` is greater than 1. That is the main issue I am facing.

Comment: Please only post relevant code. Anyway, you can simply do something like `(shopDetails && shopDetails.hours) ? shopDetails.hours.open.map(...) : <...>`

Answer (score 1):

This should work.but note that Updating Objects to state is not good idea at all because soon or later you will start missing re rendering...use array instead for storing data or permitives value...

Second You have to wait for data to arrive..no magic will going to save you...best is to show another component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import caffinderLogo from "../assets/caffinder-logo.png";
import Button from "./Button";
import "../components/CoffeeShop.css";
import { useParams, useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export default function CoffeeShop() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id, name } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const all_data = location.state?.all_data;

  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  const [shopDetails, setShopDetails] = useState({});
  const [hours, setHours] = useState([]);

  const DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];

  const MONTHS = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  let url_link_details = "http://localhost:1111/api/yelp/details";
  let url_link_reviews = "http://localhost:1111/api/yelp/reviews";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(url_link_details, {
        all_data,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        let updatedHours = response.data.hours[0];
        response.data.hours = updatedHours;
        console.log(response.data);
        setShopDetails(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(url_link_reviews, {
        all_data,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setReviews(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    // setHours(shopDetails.hours);
  }, [shopDetails]);

  const formatHours = (hour) => {
    let timing = hour.split("");
    if (timing[0] == 0) {
      timing.shift();
      timing.splice(1, 0, ":");
      timing.join("");
      return timing;
    } else {
      let time = timing[0] + timing[1];
      let newTime = parseInt(time);
      if (newTime > 12) {
        let timeOverTime = newTime - 12;
        let currentTiming = timeOverTime.toString() + ":00";
        return currentTiming;
      } else {
        timing.splice(2, 0, ":");
        timing.join("");
        return timing;
      }
    }
  };

  const formatTimeCreated = (time) => {
    let dayTime = "";
    let splitCreated = time.split(" ");
    let postDate = splitCreated[0];
    let splitDate = postDate.split("-");
    let year = splitDate[0];
    let monthInt = parseInt(splitDate[1]);
    let month = MONTHS[monthInt];
    let day = splitDate[2];
    return `${month} ${day}, ${year}`;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="shop-container">
        <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go Back</button>
        <a href={all_data.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
          <img src={all_data.image_url} className="c-s-image" alt="logo" />
        </a>
        <h1 className="shop-name">{all_data.name}</h1>
        <div className="shop-rating">
          <p>Rating: {all_data.rating} / 5</p>
          <p>Price: {all_data.price}</p>
        </div>
        <a
          href={`http://maps.google.com/?q=${all_data.location.address1} ${all_data.location.city}, ${all_data.location.state} ${all_data.location.zip_code}`}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer noopener"
        >
          <p>{all_data.location.address1}</p>
          <p>
            {all_data.location.city}, {all_data.location.state}{" "}
            {all_data.location.zip_code}
          </p>
        </a>
        <div>
          <p>Current Hours: {hours.is_open_now ? "Open" : "Closed"}</p>
----------------------------------- Considering data is available --------------------------------
          {_.isArray(shopDetails?.hours?.open?) ? shopDetails?.hours?.open?.map((hour) => {
              return (
                <div className="shop-hours">
                  <p>{DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK[hour.day]}</p>
                  <p>
                    Opens: {formatHours(hour.start)} a.m. - Closes:{" "}
                    {formatHours(hour.end)} p.m.
                  </p>
                </div>
              );
            }) : (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )}
--------------------Loading is required until hour is present----------------------------
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className="review-header">Reviews: </p>
          {reviews.map((review) => {
            return (
              <div className="review" key={review.id}>
                <div></div>
                <p>{review.user.name}</p>
                <div className="rating-created">
                  <p>Overall Rating: {review.rating} / 5</p>
                  <p>{formatTimeCreated(review.time_created)}</p>
                </div>
                <p>{review.text}</p>
                <div></div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Add A Review</legend>
            <label for="stacked-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="stacked-name" placeholder="Name" />
            <br></br>
            <label for="stacked-email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="stacked-email" placeholder="Email" />
            <br></br>
            <label for="stacked-rating">Rating</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="stacked-rating"
              min="0"
              max="5"
              step=".5"
            />
            <br></br>
            <label for="stacked-review">Review</label>
            <input type="blurb" id="stacked-review" placeholder="Review" />
            <br></br>
            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
              Add Reivew
            </button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = {
  businessInfoBox: {
    border: "solid orange 1px",
    width: "70vw",
    padding: "0 20px",
    borderRadius: 20,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "start",
  },
};
```

Comment: for this proejct, ```shopDetails.hours.open``` is an array. So I am storing the hours as an array naturally. This issue is the timing issue. There is an update I am posting to the original question that might clarify more.

Comment: You have to consider the Loading component if there is a delay in data arrival..Second, it will be good if you use a different setState component for that.